# Notepad++ -> finding records that do not match a specific pattern after the nth occurrence of a string

Tags: notepad++

I am struggling trying to come up with a regex in Notepad++ to identify situations where I am looking for specific text after the nth occurrence of a character.  I haven't really touched regex that much recently so I am very rusty and could use some help!

Here is an example dataset:

OK -> "Field1","Field2","Field3","Field4","Field5","Field6","Field7","Field8","Field9","Field10"

Error -> "Field1","Field2","Field3","Field4","Field5","Field6","Field7","Field8","9Field","Field10"

In this case, I want to identify records that have [^F] after the 17th occurrence of a double quote .. or the 8th occurrence of a comma. I can select the text using ^(?:.*?"){17} ... but can't figure out how to get the [^F] to fit in to the expression.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Wanting a `[^F]` means wanting any character that is not an `F`. Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I am looking to identify any record that does not start with the text Field after a the 17th double quote.  Some examples of errors would be "ABC123","123","ield9" .. etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
("[^"]+",){8}"[^F]
```

- `"[^"]+",` matches any quoted string followed by a coma;
- `("[^"]+"){8}"` matches exactly 8 quoted strings concatenated, each followed by a coma.

If the matches must not span over multiple lines, add `^` at the beginning of the regex.

Note that this solution does not work if there are spaces after the comas, or escaped quotes, but if needed it can be easily adapted.

Edit: since you didn't mention coma, here's a solution that does not depend on comas: `^("[^"]+){16}"[^F]`.

Comment: Have you tested these on Notepad++? I think none of them work because `[^"]` and also `[^F]` will match `\r` and `\n` characters.

Comment: Yes, it tested them with the two provided sample lines. If you need the result to be contained in a single line, add `^` at the beginning of the line (once!), and use `[^F\r\n]` instead of `[^F]`.

Comment: I did not provide the samples. Please test your REs with a file containing two or more shorter lines.

Comment: Thank You!  I just ran the expression and it returned records that matched my expectation.